# AngularJS: pass data from controller to app config

Tags: angularjs, global-variables, angular-http-interceptors

I'm quite new to Angular. I'm using token authentication in my Angular app. I use HTTP interceptor to check when my backend returns 401, and than do a login using a refresh token:

```
myapp.config(...)
...
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$injector', function($q, $injector) {
  var sessionRecoverer = {
    responseError: function(response) {
      // Session has expired
      if (response.status === 401) {
        var $http = $injector.get('$http');
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var $auth = $injector.get('$auth');

        $auth.login({
          refresh_token: ????,
          grant_type: 'refresh_token',
          event_client: 'client',
          client_id: 'id'
        });

        // When the session recovered, make the same backend call again and chain the request
        return deferred.promise.then(function() {
          return $http(response.config);
        });
      }
      return $q.reject(response);
    }
  };
  return sessionRecoverer;
}]);
```

Now, the refresh_token comes from my login controller (which pulls it from the api backend). So the controller has to pass it somehow to the interceptor. The problem is that the interceptor is in the config block so there are no services, values, etc. - only providers. But the providers are not injectable into the controller. So is there a way to pass data from controller to app.config? If not, is there a workaround? Can the injector be anywhere else other than app.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it simply like this :

```
    myapp.config(...)
    ...
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$injector', function($q, $injector, TokenFactory) {
      var sessionRecoverer = {
        responseError: function(response) {
          // Session has expired
          if (response.status === 401) {
            var $http = $injector.get('$http');
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var $auth = $injector.get('$auth');

            $auth.login({
              refresh_token: TokenFactory.getRefreshToken(),
              grant_type: 'refresh_token',
              event_client: 'client',
              client_id: 'id'
            });

            // When the session recovered, make the same backend call again and chain the request
            return deferred.promise.then(function() {
              return $http(response.config);
            });
          }
          return $q.reject(response);
        }
      };
      return sessionRecoverer;
    }]);
```

As you say, the block config can only inject providers, but the interceptor, itself, is a factory, thus you can inject other factories, for example, a factory called TokenFactory that should provide a method that return the refresh token when needed.

### Edit

If the refresh_token is a thing that comes from the backend and you want to set a value within TokenFactory from your login controller, you can do something like this to implement your factory and your controller :

```
myapp.factory('TokenFactory',function(){

  var currentRefreshToken;

  return {
    setRefreshToken: function(token){
      currentRefreshToken = token;
    },
    getRefreshToken: function(){
      return currentRefreshToken:
    }
  };
});

myapp.controller('MyLoginCtrl',function($scope,TokenFactory,$http){

  $scope.login = function(){
    $http.post('http://myapp.com/refreshtoken',$scope.credentials)
      .then(TokenFactory.setRefreshToken)
      .then(function(){ /* ... */})
      .catch(function(err){ console.error(err) })
    ;
  };

});
```

### Data persistance

If you want to make your tokens to persist, you can write a factory that use the `LocalStorage HTML5 API` and use it in your `TokenFactory`:

```
myapp.factory('TokenFactory',function(LocalStorage){

  // load the value from localstorage (hard disk) on app starts
  var currentRefreshToken = LocalStorage.get('myapp.currentRefreshToken');

  return {
    setRefreshToken: function(token){
      currentRefreshToken = token; // save value in RAM
      LocalStorage.set('myapp.currentRefreshToken',token); // and sync the localstorage value
    },
    getRefreshToken: function(){
      return currentRefreshToken; // quick access to the value from RAM
    }
  };
});

myapp.factory('LocalStorage',function($window) {

    var localStorage = {};

    localStorage.set = function(key, value) {
        $window.localStorage[key] = value;
    };
    localStorage.get = function(key, defaultValue) {
        return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
    };
    localStorage.setObject = function(key, value) {
        $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
    };
    localStorage.getObject = function(key) {
        return (!$window.localStorage[key] || $window.localStorage[key] === undefined) ? {} : JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key]);
    };
    localStorage.setArray = function(key, array){
        if (!array.length) {
            console.debug(array);
            $window.localStorage[key] = '[]';
        } else{
            this.setObject(key, array);                    
        }
    };
    localStorage.getArray = function(key){
        return (!$window.localStorage[key] || $window.localStorage[key] === undefined) ? [] : JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key]);
    };
    localStorage.exportAsFile = function(key, fileName){        
        var data = [$window.localStorage[key]] || ['{}'];
        var blob = new Blob(data,{type:'application/json;charset=utf-8'});
        $window.saveAs(blob,fileName);
    };
    return localStorage;
});
```

Comment: I should've mentioned, the refresh_token is a thing that comes from the backend, I don't generate it in the front end. Can I set a value within TokenFactory from my login controller?

Comment: Getting `Cannot read property 'getRefreshToken' of undefined`. If I also inject it into the .config, I get `[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: TokenFactory`

Comment: No you mustn't inject it into .config block. You said it yourself, only providers can be injected into these blocks. This is why you get `Unknow provider` error. The first error (`Cannot read property...`) means something is wrong in your definition/declaration of the `TokenFactory`. Please send me your whole code I will look at where is your mistake. Its probably a little oversight some where. Please post me your entire code files (html+js) in a zip file at <my-mail>

Comment: I received your code. Indeed, when you declare your factory `$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$injector', function($q, $injector, TokenFactory){ ... }]);`, you missed to annotate `TokenFactory` cause it is not seen by angular (because you used injector annotations for $q and $injector. If not, it would work) . Remove `$q` and `$injector` annotations or add the `TokenFactory` annotation : `$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$injector', 'TokenFactory', function($q, $injector, TokenFactory){ ... }]);` and it will work.

Comment: If you think I helped you with my answer, remember that you can accept it clicking the check mark at the left of the begining of my answer, and also you can upvote my answer clicking the UP button on top of the check mark.

Comment: Yep, that works, the only problem is that it doesn't persist on browser refresh, so it has to be stored somewhere. Edited your answer to add that.

Comment: Of course, a single page application (as angular apps are) should'nt be refreshed. However, a good application should persist its data (and its routes and states) if the reload occurs. So, you're right, you have to choose a storage solution (like localStorage, sessionStorage, indexdb ...)